# How to run Tornado's Future from function instead of yielding

Tags: python, asynchronous, web, tornado

I have something like this:

```
@coroutine
def foo(): # it can be a http-handler method
    bar()

def bar() # it must be 'next()' of iterator
    # How to run from here foo_2?

@coroutine
def foo_2(): # Something asynchronous
    ....
```

Actually, I want to make an iterator which operates with REST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to use a `Future` in Tornado you must either yield it in a coroutine or use its `add_done_callback` method to wait for it to finish, and only then can you use the `result` method to see the result.

Unfortunately this means it is not really possible to work with Futures in a synchronous context like `for` loop iteration. Instead, your iterator will have to produce Futures that the caller must yield (and the caller must therefore be a coroutine):

```
for future in my_iterator():
    result = yield future
```

There is more discussion of different patterns for iteration in this [blog post](http://emptysqua.re/blog/motor-iterating-over-results/). It's slightly outdated now since it was written for Tornado 2.x and uses `gen.engine` and `gen.Task` instead of `gen.coroutine`, but the same general principles still apply.

Answer (score 1):

Since `foo_2` returns a [Future](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future), you need to get the result manually:

```
def bar():
    value = foo_2().result()
```